# how can I add custum command to freebsd kernel?

Tags: freebsd

I installed freebsd to do my school homework. I have to add custom function or cammand to freebsd kernel and recompile kernel.
Is there any good tutorial for this?
should I install free bsd in specific way like kernel developer?

Comment: Start with the FreeBSD Handbook. It's available on the FreeBSD site and is also available from the ports collection. If you've never even installed FreeBSD, starting with kernel programming is a bit much, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

"Commands" have nothing to do with the kernel; they are ordinary userspace programs.

As for function - do you perhaps mean syscall?  If so, this should help you: https://wiki.freebsd.org/AddingSyscalls.  For homework you can safely ignore things like Capsicum, MAC, auditing, or compatibility.